# Qual a Connection String usada para fazer a ligação entre Cobol e B.D. Oracle?

Tags: oracle, connectionstring, cobol

Não consigo fazer a ligação entre um programa Micro Focus `Cobol` e a base de dados `Oracle`.

Estou a usar o comando:

```
EXEC SQL
     CONNECT :USERNAME IDENTIFIED BY :PASSWD
END-EXEC
```

O erro que me devolve é:

> Please specify Database name

Já tentei outras formas de ligação, mas não consigo conectar-me.

Comment: Pode voce mostrar as definições de suas variáveis ​​do anfitrião?

Comment: LISTENER=
  (description=
    (address_list)=
      (address=(protocol=tcp)(host=127.0.0.1)(port=1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=chave))
  )

  SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = orcl)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /home/cat/app/cat/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin)
      (PROGRAM = dg4odbc)
    )
   )
   ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /home/cat/app/cat/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/oracle

Comment: # tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /home/cat/app/cat/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
 /home/cat/app/cat/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

 LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC))
      )

 ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT= 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl))
  )

Comment: USERNAME and PASSWD. Definicoes em COBOL WORKING-STORAGE SECTION, sff.

Comment: Já experimentei com USERNAME='JEFF' e PASSWD='ORACLEPASSWORD', que foi um utilizador que criei no sqlplus. Agora estou a tentar com:        01 dsn      pic x(130) value "Driver={Oracle ODBC Driver};
      - "Dbq=ORCL.SITE;Uid=sys;Pwd=africa12;".

Answer (score 0):

Desculpas pela tradução automática. Congratulo-me com a ajuda dos editores (tem sido algum tempo desde a última vez).

---

COBOL não tem "strings", no sentido de que não há campo com um terminal (como um nulo ou uma nova linha) que COBOL iria interpretar como sendo o fim de pedaço de dados.

COBOL tem campos de comprimento fixo.

Como o Oacle sabe quanto tempo tem sua senha de usuário e senha? Não.

Você precisa descobrir como a Oracle pode entender o comprimento de seus dados.

A primeira abordagem é consultar a documentação Pro * COBOL (Oracle COBOL). Lá você verá uma definição de dados incluindo VARYING para o userid e senha.

VARYING (nesse contexto particular) pertence a Pro * COBOL. Seria considerado uma Extensão de Idioma para COBOL.

Não é claro qual COBOL compilador você está usando.

O GnuCOBOL tem ANYLENGTH, mas não está (ainda) disponível para definições WORKING-STORAGE. Micro Focus COBOL (se você estiver usando um deles) pode ter ANYLENGTH ou algo equivalente: se você consultar a documentação / knowledgebase, eu esperaria que você pode encontrar algo.

No entanto, ele pode ser feito em qualquer COBOL simples, embora você precise calcular o comprimento dos dados você mesmo (ele não será automático, ao contrário do VARYING e o ANYLENGTH).

Primeiro, você precisa entender como a Oracle espera que os dados cheguem a ele a partir do Pro * COBOL.

O que o VARYING realmente faz, pode ser definido como este:

```
01 Senha do usuário.
    05 UP-Length COMP-5 PIC 9 (4).
    05 UP-Username PIC X (30).
```

A Oracle espera um tipo "varchar". Um binário de dois bytes (inteiros) de comprimento, immediatelt antes dos dados.

Você MOVE seu userid exigido para UP-Username, então você iria trabalhar para fora quantos traiing espaços em branco há no campo, subtrair que a partir de 30, e colocar o resultado em UP-Length. Dependendo do compilador COBOL que você tem, existem maneiras mais ou menos fáceis de fazer isso.

Você precisa fazer isso para todos os campos de tipo "varchar".

Sem o comprimento antes dos dados, a Oracle teria usado os dois primeiros caracteres de dados como um inteiro binário.

---

English original:

COBOL does not have "strings", in the sense that there is no field with a terminal (like a null or a newline) which COBOL would interpret as being the end of piece of data.

COBOL has fixed-length fields.

How does Oacle know how long your userid and password are? It doesn't.

You need to find out how Oracle can understand the length of your data.

First approach is to consult the Pro*COBOL (Oracle's COBOL) documentation. There you will see a data-definition including VARYING for the userid and password.

VARYING (in that particular context) belongs to Pro*COBOL. It would be considered a Language Extension for COBOL.

It is not clear which COBOL compiler you are using.

GnuCOBOL does have ANYLENGTH, but it is not (yet) available for WORKING-STORAGE definitions. Micro Focus COBOL (if you happen to be using one of theirs) may have ANYLENGTH or something equivalent: if you consult their documentation/knowledgebase, I'd expect you may find something.

However, it can be done in any plain COBOL, although you need to work out the length of the data yourself (it will not be automatic, unlike the VARYING and the ANYLENGTH).

First, you need to understand how Oracle expects the data to arrive to it from Pro*COBOL.

What the VARYING actually does, can be defined like this:

```
01  User-Password.
    05  UP-Length              COMP-5 PIC 9(4).
    05  UP-Username                   PIC X(30).
```

Oracle expects a "varchar"-type. A two-byte binary (integer) length, immediatelt before the data.

You would MOVE your required userid to UP-Username, then you would work out how many traiing blanks there are in the field, subtract that from 30, and put the result into UP-Length. Depending on which COBOL compiler you have, there are more or less easy ways to do that.

You need to do that for all "varchar"-type fields.

Without the length before the data, Oracle would have used the first two characters of data as a binary integer.

Comment: O compilador, não me deixa fazer exactamente o que diz. Então eu fiz o seguinte:

Comment: Continuo com o mesmo erro. Working:        01  USERNAME.
           05 USERNAME-LEN PIC 9(04) COMP-5.
           05 USERNAME-NAM PIC X(04).
       01 PASSWD.
           05 PASSWD-LEN   PIC 9(04) COMP-5.
           05 PASSWD-NAM   PIC X(14).
       01 USERNAMEX        PIC X(06).
       01 PASSWDX          PIC X(16).
Procedure:             MOVE 4      TO USERNAME-LEN.
           MOVE 'JEFF' TO USERNAME-NAM.
           MOVE 14     TO PASSWD-LEN.
           MOVE 'ORACLEPASSWORD' TO PASSWD-NAM.
           MOVE USERNAME TO USERNAMEX
           MOVE PASSWD   TO PASSWDX.

Comment: se não usar as variáveis auxiliares USERNAMEX e PASSWDX, dá-me erro de compilação. estou a usar o compilador MICROFOCUS cobol.

Comment: Consegui corrigir o erro de compilação com nível 49:        01  USERNAME.
           49 USERNAME-LEN PIC 9(04) COMP-5.
           49 USERNAME-NAM PIC X(04).
       01 PASSWD.
           49 PASSWD-LEN   PIC 9(04) COMP-5.
           49 PASSWD-NAM   PIC X(14).
Contudo o erro mantêm-se: -0000019703
Please specify Database name

Comment: Your answer is a non-answer. Please consider editing.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo o manual do Micro Focus Developer, disponível clicando [aqui](https://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp) e procurando pelo termo CONNECT, o comando `CONNECT` que você está usando tem a seguinte sintaxe,

```
>>---EXEC SQL---CONNECT user--.------------------------.->
                              +-IDENTIFIED BY password-+
                              +-------'/'password------+ 

 >---.--------------.--------.--------------------.------->
     +--AT db_name--+        +--USING data_source-+

 >---.----------------------.----------------------------->
     +--WITH-.----.-PROMPT--+ 
             +-NO-+ 

 >---.-----------------------------.---END-EXEC---><
     +-RETURNING output_connection-+
```

onde `data_source` é uma fonte de dados ODBC, que deve ser previamente configurada em Menu Iniciar > Painel de Controlo > Ferramentas Administrativas > Fonte de dados ODBC; e `db_name`, no caso do SQL Server, é a base de dados à qual você quer se conectar (não está explícito no manual o caso do Oracle).

Caso queira fazer uso direto de *connection strings*, use a seguinte sintaxe,

```
>>----EXEC SQL---CONNECT USING input_connection---------->

 >-----.-------------.---.---------------------.---------->
       +--AS db_name-+   +--WITH-.----.-PROMPT-+
                                 +-NO-+

 >-----.------------------------------.------END-EXEC---->< 
       +--RETURNING output_connection-+
```

onde `input_connection` é a *connection string* própria do Oracle, armazenada na working-storage section, em um campo PIC X(n).

Um exemplo de *conn string* para Oracle, retirada [daqui](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/), segue abaixo:

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Talvez seja necessário incluir a palavra reservada `DRIVER={nomedodriver};` na *conn string*. Como diz na referência, abaixo,

> For the driver name, use the name that appears in the left-most column of the drivers tab in the ODBC control panel.

"Quanto ao nome do *driver*, use o nome que aparece na coluna mais à esquerda da aba *drivers* no painel de controlo ODBC."

Referência: https://community.microfocus.com/microfocus/cobol/extend_and_acucobol/w/knowledge_base/3996/can-you-connect-using-the-odbc-interface-without-setting-up-a-datasource